# upgrading a very old VM

Tags: upgrade, 10.04

I'm trying to upgrade a very old (Lucid Lynx) Vmware VM I recently re-discovered.

When I try to run the update manager, I get the message "Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.  You will not get any further security fixes or critical updates. Please Upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu Linux."  Then update manager freezes.  Is there a way to configure update manager so it can point to something I can upgrade to?

NOTE: I've been following some of the questions involving upgrading end-of-life versions... nothing seems to help,

Comment: 10.04 has gone end of life. At that time Ask Ubuntu also stops supporting that release. Re-installing is the only option to get that system up and running.

Comment: @guntbert - checked some of those out, but they weren't getting me where I needed to be.

Comment: Finally finagled the upgrades up to Narwal - then things went bad and I got stuck at the GRUB prompt.  So now I have a different problem ...

Comment: In that case I can only repeat the advice already given: Install a new system.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't try upgrading such an old OS.  I generally don't do upgrades, although I have with Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.  I would stand up a new VM and copy data and such over.  Far more likely to work smoothly :-)